# Python Kivy GUI looks different on seperate devices

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy

I made a GUI with Kivy. It looks great on my Laptop. But if I start the GUI on another device the widgets aren't on the same place.

It should every where looks like that:

[image: How it should look]

But for example on a Windows-Machine it looks like this (see especially the CheckBox):
[How it look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFazd.png)

First I did everything with GridLayout and with properties like 'width', 'height' and so one. Than I thought this are absolut information, I need something which is relativ to the GUI. So I change to FloatLayout and used 'pos_hint' and 'size_hint', but sadly the result is the same.

My Python Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.clock import Clock

VIDEO_DISPLAY_TIME = 4


class CalculationScreen(Screen):
    pass


class StartScreen(Screen):
    pass


class Calculation(App):
    def build(self):
        Window.size = (650, 500)
        self.title = "Calculator"
        self.screenmanager = ScreenManager()
      #  self.screenmanager.add_widget(StartScreen(name='start'))
        self.screenmanager.add_widget(CalculationScreen(name="calculation"))
        self.schedule = Clock.schedule_once(self.change_window, VIDEO_DISPLAY_TIME)
        return self.screenmanager

    def change_window(self, *args):
        self.schedule.cancel()
        self.screenmanager.transition.direction = "up"
        self.screenmanager.transition.duration = 0.01
        self.screenmanager.current = 'calculation'


def main():
    kv = Builder.load_file("calculator.kv")
    Calculation().run()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And my *.kv - file:

```
<CalculationScreen>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        rows: 4

        GridLayout:
            cols: 1
            rows: 1
            padding: 10

            Image:
                source: 'icon/logo_so.png'
                size_hint: 0.5, None
                pos_hint: {'x': 1}

        GridLayout:
            cols: 1
            rows: 1

            FloatLayout:

                Label:
                    color: 0, 0, 0, 1
                    size_hint: None, 0.9
                    pos_hint: {'x': 0.1, 'y': 0.9}
                    bold: True
                    text: "First one"

                GridLayout:
                    rows: 5
                    size_hint: 0.3, 0.6
                    pos_hint: {'x': 0.25, 'y': 0.8}

                    TextInput:
                        size_hint: None, 0.45
                        pos_hint: {'x': 0.2, 'y': 1}
                        multiline: False
                        id: first_one

                    TextInput:
                        size_hint: None, 0.45
                        pos_hint: {'x': 0.2, 'y': 8}
                        multiline: False
                        id: first_one

                    TextInput:
                        size_hint: None, 0.45
                        pos_hint: {'x': 0.2, 'y': 6}#
                        multiline: False
                        id: first_one

                    TextInput:
                        size_hint: None, 0.45
                        pos_hint: {'x': 0.2, 'y': 4}#
                        multiline: False
                        id: first_one

                    TextInput:
                        size_hint: None, 0.45
                        pos_hint: {'x': 0.2, 'y': 2}
                        multiline: False
                        id: first_one

                Label:
                    color: 0, 0, 0, 1
                    size_hint: None, 0.9
                    bold: True
                    pos_hint: {'x': 0.37, 'y': 0.9}
                    halgin: 'left'
                    text: "[ABC]"

                Label:
                    color: 0, 0, 0, 1
                    size_hint: None, 0.9
                    pos_hint: {'x': 0.1, 'y': 0.77}
                    bold: True
                    text: "Next one"

                Label:
                    color: 0, 0, 0, 1
                    size_hint: None, 0.9
                    pos_hint: {'x': 0.37, 'y': 0.77}
                    bold: True
                    halgin: 'left'
                    text: "[DFG]"

                Label:
                    color: 0, 0, 0, 1
                    size_hint: None, 0.9
                    pos_hint: {'x': 0.07, 'y': 0.65}
                    bold: True
                    text: "Something else"

                Label:
                    color: 0, 0, 0, 1
                    pos_hint: {'x': 0.37, 'y': 0.65}
                    size_hint: None, 0.9
                    bold: True
                    halgin: 'left'
                    text: "[KV]"

                Label:
                    color: 0, 0, 0, 1
                    size_hint: None, 0.9
                    pos_hint: {'x': 0.09, 'y': 0.53}
                    #height: 30
                    bold: True
                    text: "Another one"

                Label:
                    color: 0, 0, 0, 1
                    size_hint: None, 0.9
                    pos_hint: {'x': 0.37, 'y': 0.53}
                    bold: True
                    halgin: 'left'
                    text: "[XY]"

                Label:
                    color: 0, 0, 0, 1
                    size_hint: None, 0.9
                    pos_hint: {'x': 0.1, 'y': 0.4}
                    bold: True
                    text: "The Last"

                Label:
                    color: 0, 0, 0, 1
                    size_hint: None, 0.9
                    pos_hint: {'x': 0.37, 'y': 0.4}
                    bold: True
                    halgin: 'left'
                    text: "[ZZ]"

                Label:
                    color: 0, 0, 0, 1
                    size_hint: None, 0.9
                    pos_hint: {'x': 0.1, 'y': 0.25}
                    bold: True
                    halgin: 'right'
                    text: 'First'

                Label:
                    color: 0, 0, 0, 1
                    size_hint: None, 0.9
                    pos_hint: {'x': 0.3, 'y': 0.25}
                    bold: True
                    halgin: 'right'
                    text: 'Second'

                CheckBox:
                    canvas:
                        Clear:
                        Color:
                            rgba: self.color
                        Rectangle:
                            source: self._checkbox_image
                            size: sp(32), sp(32)
                            pos: int(self.center_x - sp(30)), int(self.center_y - sp(50))
                    color: 1, 0, 0, 1
                    size_hint: None, None
                    pos_hint: {'x': 0.2, 'y': 0.64}
                    group: 'kind_of_calculation'
                    halgin: 'left'
                    id: first

                CheckBox:
                    canvas:
                        Clear:
                        Color:
                            rgba: self.color
                        Rectangle:
                            source: self._checkbox_image
                            size: sp(32), sp(32)
                            pos: int(self.center_x - sp(30)), int(self.center_y - sp(50))
                    color: 1, 0, 0, 1
                    size_hint: None, None
                    pos_hint: {'x': 0.4, 'y': 0.64}
                    group: 'kind_of_calculation'
                    id: second

                Label:
                    color: 0, 0, 0, 1
                    size_hint: None, None
                    pos_hint: {'x': 0.2, 'y': 0.1}
                    bold: True
                    id: result
                    text: 'Here I am, the result or the error message'

                Button:
                    size_hint: 0.2, 0.2
                    pos_hint: {'x': 0.7, 'y': 0.2}
                    text: 'Calculate'
                    on_release: root.calculate()
```

Comment: Show us (or describe) exactly what you expect to see and exactly what do you see that you believe in incorrect.

Comment: I expect the GUI on any device to look like the first picture in my post. The labels and especially the checkboxes change their position on different devices. I have edited my post and added an example image of how it looks on another device I have access to.